# x:set not working the same on 2 different machines?

Tags: java, xslt, jstl

I'm using JSTL to parse an XML file so that I can display items on a webpage.  I use the xml tags from JSTL to assist in this, but an finding a strange inconsistency between machines.

```
<x:set var="test1" select="$extraSideNavLinks/sideNavLinks/@perm"/>
<x:set var="test2" select="string($extraSideNavLinks/sideNavLinks/@perm)"/>
TEST1: ${test1}
TEST2: ${test2}
```

On my development machine, I get the following (which is what I expect):

- TEST1: [perm="ROLE_USER"]
- TEST2: ROLE_USER

On another development server, I'm getting a different answer:

- TEST1: [perm="ROLE_USER"]
- TEST2:

For some reason, the `string` xslt function isn't selecting the text from XML attribute as I expect.

As far as I can tell, the Jetty version, java version and OS versions are the same on both machines (and the XML file is identical), but that `string()` function isn't working on one of the machines.  Has anyone had a similar problem, or suggestions on how to investigate why the difference is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll throw up my workaround incase anyone else has this issue in the future.

No matter what I did, I couldn't figure out why some machines were just refusing to recognise/implement the string() xpath function, so I worked around the problem by changing my code to the following:

```
    <c:set var="test2">
        <x:out select="$extraSideNavLinks/sideNavLinks/@perm"/>
    </c:set>
```

This worked consistently on all machines.

Comment: I had same issue, thanks for comment it seems a bug in jstl 2!